# Use of __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED without comparison

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

In AFNetworking 2.0, NSHTTPSessionManager.h has the following code:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#else
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif
```

__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED is used without specifying a version to compare to. Why? Is it because this macro is defined when Core Services framework is changed to MobileCoreServices.h?

Comment: You'd have to check this, but I suppose on MacOS X __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED will not be defined.

Comment: Great guess - is CoreServices for OSX? Is there no other way to differentiate between iOS and OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a check if the device is an iOS device or an OS X one. `MobileCoreServices` is used on iOS while `CoreServices` is used on OS X.

`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` is only defined on iOS, which is why this works. The other check is `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`, which is only defined on OS X and can therefore be used in the reverse fashion.

This is a bad check, and shouldn't be done. One should create separate frameworks for each platform. I guess they did this because it might save some hard disk space, as the rest of the framework is probably nearly identical.